# PHP Strategy Game Map - Drawing Map & Objects

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently making a strategy game. So far, my only problem has been the map. For example, on most of the browser games, there is a map on which you can see nearby players and pretty much all players. I'm trying to create the concept of how to acomplish that but im kinda failing.

So far, here are my thoughs:

- Step 1: User Registers - 2 mysql table columns contain his X and Y
  coordinates which are 2 random numbers between X and X. We can
  generate the two numbers in the following way: `mt_rand(0,256);`
- Step 2: Im    stuck here :( I suppose we have to draw all of the villages on the map?

---

I would appreciate if someone could help

Comment: I'd suggest that `mt_rand(256,256);` is a bit like playing with loaded dice

Comment: `mt_rand(256,256);` is very strange. The first argument should be `min`, the second `max`. Having `min === max` makes no sense. I think you mean: `mt_rand(0,255);`

Comment: yes, sorry. edited the post

Comment: What do you guys think about this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

Comment: I'm afraid this question is essentially the same as, "how do I make a user interface for a game?"  It's just far too broad.  Are you stuck on positioning elements on a given map drawing?  What is that drawing?  What technologies/techniques are you using to position those elements?  You're trying to create a game, and the part where you're "stuck" is "creating a game."

Comment: I have created the game. I want to add a map feature and I cant think of how to do it.

Comment: No offence but if you can't figure out step 2 then I think you should be going back to basics a little bit rather than creating a full fledged strategy game. Break the problem down a little and come back with another question.